# Automapper incorrectly populating parent/child structure

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following entity classes, which are mapped from virtually identical view model classes:

```
public class Node
{
    public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Tree
{
    public Node Root { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following view model structure

```
Tree 
    -> Root
        -> Children { node1, node2 }
```

Once the view model is mapped to the entity, the first child node, of the root node, is the root node and, as a result, I'm getting an infinite loop when I traverse the entity object structure.

Anybody have an idea why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Many thanks

Steve

Comment: Could you post your AutoMapper Configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<NodeViewModel, Node>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Children, 
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children.Select(nodevm => Mapper.Map<NodeViewModel, Node>(nodevm)).ToList()))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Parent,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<NodeViewModel, Node>(src.Parent)))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Text,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Text));
```

Something like that schould work as the AutoMapper Configuration.

PS: I did not try it by now, but as I use the AutoMapper very often I think it should work.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I ended up using but it's close enough.  The problem with this, though, is that AutoMapper is supposed to automatically do this for you.

Comment: Hi Steven, what did you change? I double checked it, and it seems that I forgot to map the src.Parent? Am I right? Thx